# How to add rows in devexpress GridControl just like we add rows in a normal datagridview. (WinForms C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datagridview, devexpress

I wonder if there is an option to add rows in devexpress GridControl just like we add rows in a normal datagridview.

I dont have a datatable or datasource at this point of adding rows. When the application loads, I should be able to insert rows to the gridview manually. It can be done in a normal datagridview Like this :

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
```

I am working on WinForms in C#.
I cant find an option in devexpress gridview to do this.

Thanks
Rahul

Answer (score 4):

To be able to add rows in your grid :

. Your gridDataSource property should be set (Like Fares wrote)

. Make your view editable

```
myView.OptionsBehavior.Editable = true;
```

. Set the position of the NewItemRowPosition of your view

```
myView.OptionsView.NewItemRowPosition = NewItemRowPosition.Bottom;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why you don't have a data source and what stops you from creating one.

The most correct way to achieve what you want to do is to build a `List` of objects that you want to show and then affect as the data source of the `GridControl`

```
List<MyClass> myClassList = new List<MyClass>();
// Here, you build your list as if you were to build your "rows"

// Finally, you can do this
gridControl1.DataSource = myClassList;
```

DevExpress creates the columns and fills the data.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, you have to use a DataTable assign it as DataSource - have a look at this code snipped:

```
    Dim dataTable As DataTable = New DataTable

    dataTable.Columns.Add(Me.GridColumn1.FieldName)
    dataTable.Columns.Add(Me.GridColumn2.FieldName)
    dataTable.Columns.Add(Me.GridColumn3.FieldName)
    dataTable.Columns.Add(Me.GridColumn4.FieldName)

    For Each pic In collectionToShow
        Dim row As DataRow = dataTable.NewRow()
        row(Me.GridColumn1.FieldName) = pic.Name
        row(Me.GridColumn2.FieldName) = pic.Town
        row(Me.GridColumn3.FieldName) = pic.Alias
        row(Me.GridColumn4.FieldName) = pic.Somevalue
        dataTable.Rows.Add(row)
    Next

    gcPcoSelection.DataSource = dataTable
```

Don't forget do assign a FieldName in the GridColumns in DevExpress-Designer, otherwise the Fields will be empty. This is VB.net, but can be done 1:1 in C#, and btw, I don't understand how DevExpress could make simple tasks that hard.